# How to grep files that contains ONLY numbers?

Tags: linux, grep

Im trying to grep names of txt files containing numbers and numbers only, but I have no idea if grep is even suitable for that job.

if I have files like below...

```
FILE1: 12324
FILE2: 12345q
FILE3: qqerxv
```

It should give me only the name of `FILE1`.

I've tried `grep -r -l [a-zA-Z]` but that gives me the opposite.

What pattern should I use? What should I do to grep everything but files containing anything but numbers

How do I grep files that contains ONLY numbers?

Answer (score 4):

`grep -r -L "[^0-9 ]" .`

`[^0-9 ]` will match anything that doesn't contain digits or spaces (thought that would be fitting or else all files that contain spaces and number would be discarded).

The `-L` flag is `--files-without-match`, so this basically gives you files that DO contain digits or spaces.

Inverting the search is way better than searching for files containing [a-zA-Z] because this search would break if any other special characters (_=+&...) are in there.

Btw, the `-r` flag will search recursively in the current directory. If you want only to search the files in the current directory I suggest removing the `-r` and substituting the `.` with an `*` or just simply substitute it with the name of a single file you want to match.

Comment: The `[:digit:]` character class is probably safer than 0-9. Then you may consider dealing with `read -r decimal_point thousands_sep < <(locale LC_NUMERIC)` to include these in your pattern.

Comment: Thank you, thats what i Needed. Im grateful !

Answer (score 0):

Please use the regex pattern:  `\b([0-9])*\b`

This should help you to grep the lines that contains the only numbers.

Now to extract the name of the file from the output of above you may `cut` command, by *piping* the output of `grep?  to`cut`, i.e.

```
cat data.txt | grep \b([0-9])*\b | cut -f 1 -d ":"
```

Here I have assumed you have stored the list of your filenames in the file `data.txt`.

Options used in `grep`:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `[0-9]` -- match only a digit
- `()` -- grouping

Options used in `cut`:

- `f` -- to select the field
- `d` -- to specify delimiter

Comment: The [`cat` is useless](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and fetches the *text,* not the *file names,* from `data.txt`.

Comment: Also, the arguments to `grep` are not options.

Answer (score 0):

These `awk` should do:

```
awk '!/[^0-9]/ {print FILENAME}' FILE*
awk '!/[a-zA-Z]/ {print FILENAME}' FILE*
FILE1
```

It will print all `Filenames` from files that do only contain digits